# Help with finding correct bounds of integral in exponential distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, density-function, exponential-distribution

The average time that a light bulb burns before it fails is 1000 hours. The probability that this light bulb burns between 100 and 1000 hours before failure is:____. (3 decimal places)

$$λ = \frac{1 \ \text{failure}}{1000 \ \text{hours}}$$
$$Pr(100<X<1000) =\int_{100}^{1000}  \ \frac{1}{1000}e^{- \frac{1}{1000}x}\ \, dx = 0.536957...$$

The correct answer however is $0.0537$ and I have no idea as to how they got that answer and why the correct answer = $Pr(100<X<1000) / 10 $

Comment: Hmmm.  As you state, it seems "they" divided the correct answer by 10.